# Twilio - Send HTTP Request to Endpoint When SMS Message is Received

Tags: twilio, twilio-php

I am looking to get the message body and the sending number of a text message every time someone texts my Twilio number.  I'd like to have Twilio send either a GET or POST request (akin to a GitHub service hook) to my endpoint every time a new message is received.

I see the Request URL feature in the manage number section, but I don't see any message info being sent through that request when my number receives a text.

Is it possible to get the sender's number and the message body right now from a hook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information you are looking for is in the request to your endpoint.

When Twilio receives a message for one of your Twilio numbers it makes a synchronous HTTP request to the message URL configured for that number (just like a browser posting a form).

If your Twilio SMS webhook is configured with 'HTTP POST' you can get all the values from `$_POST` something like this:

```
foreach ($_POST as $param_name => $param_val) {
    // do something with $param_name and $param_val
}
```

or for the message body and the sending number:

```
$message_body = $_POST['Body'];
$sending_number = $_POST['From'];
```

More info in the docs:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/twilio_request

Comment: Alex, this is helpful. Could you please post same thing for c# WEB API.. How can I read the message using C#?

Comment: @MARKANDBhatt take a look at this https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/csharp/mvc

Comment: Alex, went through the link. Nothing helpful.

Comment: Alex, have a look to my question http://stackoverflow.com/q/38464416/988864